# Importing only part of data from MS Access to RStudio

Tags: ms-access, partial, rstudio

Is it possible to import part of the data from MS Access into RStudio?

We have a certain table in MS Access and would want to do analysis on just part of it at a time, so we would be interested in importing just part of it each and every single time. All the codes that we've found were on how to import the whole table into R and then partialing it all in R.

Comment: You need to write SQL. Is [this](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dbinterface.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: What does your query look like right now? How are you brining it into R?